# iOS App Store - How to have a build for iphone and ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

First time submitting an app to the app store, and we have a build for iPhone, as well as iPad, in which the difference is just selecting the build target in Xcode | General | Target Devices. On Itunes connect there doesn't seem a way to have two IPAs, one for iphone and one for ipad, so how do you support both? Do you have to have a seperate app for both iphone and ipad?

Comment: Why don't you have just one universal app instead of two separate apps?

Comment: Yeah this is the solution. We changed to iphone universal and it looks good on both iPhone and iPads. Thank you.